# Trying to build conf for sshlib2 and get error

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, libssh2

The error I got:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/user/Desktop/libssh2-1.4.3# ./buildconf 
./buildconf: 15: ./buildconf: aclocal:   not found
./buildconf: 16: ./buildconf: autoheader: not found
./buildconf: 21: ./buildconf: autoconf:   not found
./buildconf: 22: ./buildconf: automake:   not found
```

Comment: if `sudo apt-get install build-essentials` doesn't give you aclocal et al, then try `sudo apt-get install automake` (the `#` in the answer implies to run the command at a root prompt, using `sudo` allows you to accomplish it from a standard user shell)

Answer (score 0):

Install build-essential:

```
# apt-get install build-essential
```